# What do we call the ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(X)$ associated with an $R$-module $X$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology, modules, representation-theory, noncommutative-algebra

First, a convention: given an abelian group $X$, write $\mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(X)$ for the set of all group homomorphisms $$X \rightarrow X.$$

Now let $R$ denote a ring.

> **Question.** Given an $R$-module $X$, what do we call the corresponding ring homomorphism $f:R \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(X)$ given as follows? $$f(r) = \mathop{\lambda}_{x:X} rx$$

The "representor" of $X$, perhaps?

Comment: What does the $\mathop{\lambda}_{x:X}$ mean?

Comment: @rschwieb, oh nothing, just [the most fundamental quantifier ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) :). Most mathematicians would probably write this $(x:X \mapsto rx)$ or something like that, but I prefer to avoid notation that makes things "look" special.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I had a feeling that's what you were talking about, but I feel it's best to ask if the notation isn't familiar. I've seen the image of this map, and its other-handed counterpart, discussed as sets, but I don't know I've seen a particular name for the function. The place most memorable about these for me is in Jacobson's Basic Algebra books. "Representor" is a pretty good working name, but it probably needs a side associated (?)

Comment: That is, the sidedness of the module.

Comment: @rschwieb, certainly if $M$ is a bimodule, the reader needs a way of know whether we mean the left "representor" or the right.

Comment: I was just thinking that representors of right modules would be fundamentally different since they map $R$ via a ring anti-homomorphism, so I wasn't sure you'd call them the same thing.

Comment: @rschwieb, ahh good point. So maybe "corepresentor" or "contrarepresentor" or "antirepresentor" or "skewrepresentor" for the right version.

Comment: Serious question, not being snarky: why does it matter? What use is this object? Thanks!

Comment: @AlexYoucis, I've change the question a bit... the point really is that if $X$ is an abelian group, then a bilinear action $R,X \rightarrow X$ (which makes $X$ into a module) is the same thing as a ring homomorphism $R \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(X)$. They're "the same" so to speak. So this is just another perspective on what an $R$-module is. Sometimes, the latter perspective is clearer. For example, we can consider the kernel $I$ of the arrow $R \rightarrow \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(X)$, and we can quotient out $R$ by $I$. This gives a (bilinear) action of $R/I$ on $X$.

Comment: ... But, this isn't so obvious if all we're thinking about is the bilinear map $R,X \rightarrow X$.